# Python regex search for alphanumeric characters and forward slash

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find if a word matches the following conditions:

- uses only alphanumeric (and underscore) characters and optionally also a forward slash.
- is 1 or 2 lines
- has 1-4 characters per line

My attempt:

```
pattern = r"\w{1,4}(\n[^\/]\w{1,4})?"
return bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, word))
```

For e.g. it should return a match if the `word` matches all the conditions.

Here are some examples:

- "EYE"
- "EYE\n1/2"
- "SOFT\nTISS"
- "BLAD\n2"

The alphanumeric part works, but not the forward slash `[^\/]` addition. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `[^\/]` is a *negated* character class, you need a simple `/` instead. Could you please explain what contexts the slash may appear in? Can it appear once per line? Or can it be only when the string is one-line long?

Comment: It'd probably be very useful if you include a couple of examples of such words.

Comment: Added some examples in the original post

Comment: If you want to only allow a single `/` anywhere in the string, you should consider `r"^(?!(?:[^/]*/){2})[\w/]{1,4}(?:\n[\w/]{1,4})?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: `[^\/]` matches any character different from a forward slash. `\w` does not match slashes.

Use

```py
pattern = r"(?=(?:[^/]*/)?[^/]*$)[\w/]{1,4}(\n[\w/]{1,4})?"
return bool(re.fullmatch(pattern, word))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hDAgO1/1).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w/]{1,4}               any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), '/' (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w/]{1,4}               any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '/' (between 1 and 4 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolau4pCgzL71YwVYhWsk10lVJRwFExeQZ6huB2MH@biExeSGewcEgnpOPo0tMnpFSLFdafpFCsUJmngJUvxWXAhAUANklGkn5@TkaRal6aaU5ObmJJckZGkXqGva2GvZW0XH6sVr6mvZgWkUzOqZcP7baUMekViMmD8HRtFfXUSjW1NT8/x8A)**:

```py
import re
strings = ["EYE", "EYE\n1/2", "SOFT\nTISS", "BLAD\n2"]
for s in strings:
    print(bool(re.fullmatch(r'(?=(?:[^/]*/)?[^/]*$)[\w/]{1,4}(\n[\w/]{1,4})?', s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `/`, simply use `r'/'`

This should match all your examples:

```py
r'\w{1,4}(\n[\w/]{1,4})?'
```

Comment: In this case, `^` and `$` are redundant as OP uses `re.fullmatch` that requires a full string match.

Comment: aha, did not notice that!